# php Array function. Trying to avoid unpacking array and then repacking array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is there an easier way to explode one piece of an array into an additional array rather than unpacking the array, running the explode function and then repackging the array like shown below. This works fine, Im trying to find out if theres an easier way.

```
    public function getStandardizationTerms()
    {

        $statement = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$this->std_table);
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $new_result = array();
        foreach($result as $term) {
            // the only purpose of this foreach loop is to turn the exception tables field into an array
            $new_result[] = array(              
                'key'          => $term['key'],
                'operator'     => $term['operator'],
                'fragment'     => $term['fragment'],
                'manufacturer' => $term['manufacturer'],
                'is_exception' => $term['is_exception'],
                'tables'       => explode(",",$term['tables'])
            );

        }       
        return $new_result;

    }
```

Comment: normalize your DB so you have don't have multiple independent-ish bits of data in a single field.

Comment: This is only for one small piece of my application which is only going to be used by me. In this one particular field, its much easy to enter comma separated values in one field

Comment: doesn't matter. think of how ugly it is to find a specific bit of data in that field. e.g. `1|10|100|1000`. matching `100` can't be just `WHERE field LIKE %100%` because that'd match the 1000 as well. Then there's deleting values, blah blah blah. It's a horrible design and WILL bite you in the ass in the very near future.

Comment: If you really insist on going that way, you could maybe use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). But I'd still follow @MarcB's suggestion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just reference the field directly?

```
<?php
$myArray = Array ('field1' => "var1", 'field2' => "var2", 'field3' => "var3, var4, var5");
$myArray['field3'] = explode (",", $myArray['field3']);
print_r ($myArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to create a new array if you loop trough `$terms` by reference

```
foreach($result as &$term) {
    $term['tables'] = explode(",",$term['tables']);
}
```

Also take a look at the second example on http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php